# Stack overlayed divs with absolute position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im generating a div containing [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) (color picker) elements.These divs are inserted in a HTML page depending on IDs.My first result was a distorted display of my targeted div as following

[image]

Thus i added a position absolute to my inserted div and made it so it's clear of my HTML but still follows my target.

[image]

the problem im having now is that with multiple inserted DIVs on the same HTML target they overlay on top of each other.Im searching for a way to stack them up so they can all be visible without distorting my HTML target.

My inserted Div code :

```
<div id="colorpicker1" style=" position:absolute; display:block; width:450px; margin-top:-10%; left:1px; z-index:5;">
<div class="well" style=" position:relative;  width:450px;  left:1px; z-index:5;" >
    <button class="jscolor{valueElement:'+Myvalue+', styleElement:'+Myvalueid+'}">
        Click here to pick a color
    </button>
    Value: 
    <input id="+Myvalue+"  >
</div>
```

What i want to achieve is this

[image]

Comment: Is better use a CSS file instead of inline CSS. I think the best approach is wrapping all the colorpickers with another `div` and set the position absolute to this one. Then each `div` colopicker should have `display: block`.

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres testing out directly inline swtiching it as soon as i can find a solution
Problem is each color picker is generated independently and i can't warp them unless i insert all of them in a div with JS  which will deam to be difficult to sort i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve what you need to, simply by applying `display:inline-block` to both the left-hand `div` (`#colorpicker1`) and the right-hand `div`.

**Example:**

```css
.color-picker {
display: inline-block;
width:450px;
vertical-align: top;
}

.right-block {
display: inline-block;
width:450px;
height:450px;
background-color:rgb(0,127,0);
}

.well {
width: 400px;
margin: 2px;
padding: 12px 0 12px 12px;
background-color:rgb(239,239,239);
border: 2px solid rgb(214,214,214);
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-picker">
<div class="well">
<button>Click here to pick a color</button>
Value: 
<input />
</div>

<div class="well">
<button>Click here to pick a color</button>
Value: 
<input />
</div>

<div class="well">
<button>Click here to pick a color</button>
Value: 
<input />
</div>

<div class="well">
<button>Click here to pick a color</button>
Value: 
<input />
</div>

<div class="well">
<button>Click here to pick a color</button>
Value: 
<input />
</div>
</div>

<div class="right-block">
</div>
```

If you have any questions about how the CSS in the snippet above works, please ask in the comments below.